# Only getting one record returned

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

So I'm trying to retrieve a list of likes. Here's my code

```
//Echo total likes of #68
$stmt1 = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE liked_post_id = :id;");
$stmt1->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->execute();
$count = $stmt1->rowCount();
echo $count;
```

I'd assume that this would return all likes. But I only get 1 returned. Here's the structure

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| liked_post_id   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| liked_post_user | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| liked_post_ip   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And a quick query

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| id | liked_post_id | liked_post_user | liked_post_ip |
+----+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 77 | 68            | alex            | 127.0.0.1     |
| 78 | 68            | andrew          | 127.0.0.1     |
+----+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

So instead of getting `1` i'd expect to get `2`, since two users liked it. Any ideas? Also I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: I don't know PDO, but it looks like you're asking for a count of the rows returned, which would indeed be `1`... but the _value contained in the row_ would be `2`.  `COUNT(...)` is an aggregate function, so it condenses rows, essentially.

Comment: You just asked for the count, not the contents of the rows.

Comment: The `COUNT(*)` returns a single row (which contains 2). But then you ask for the count of rows, which is 1. Either remove the `COUNT(*)` or get the contents of the row returned, not their count.

Comment: Just wondering how this question managed to get so many upvotes. Mystery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$stmt1 = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM likes WHERE liked_post_id = :id;");
$stmt1->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->execute();
$row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['count'];
```

The query returns 1 row, and the *contents* of that row is the count of matching rows in the table. You need to fetch the row to read that value.

Comment: I had a typo, `$stmt` should be `$stmt1`.

Comment: I thought count was a reserved word in sql? Try changing `AS count` to `AS result_num` or something.

Comment: No, it's not a reserved word. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html for the list of reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

COUNT() is an aggregate function and therefore, returning the number of rows as result. If you'd like to get the list, you should replace COUNT(*) with *.

```
SELECT likes.* FROM likes WHERE liked_post_id = :id
```

Comment: But this is an expensive way to do it. You don't need to return all the contents of the rows if you just want the count.

Comment: So you're saying it would take more time, or would cost more since it needs more power? @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar: If I didn't misunderstand, OP was trying to retrieve a "list" of likes (line 1)

Comment: No, he's just trying to get the number of likes, not a list of them. That's why he uses `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @Barmar: Maybe OP should change the very first line of the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the query result (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE liked_post_id = :id;`):

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 2        |
+----------+
```

`rowCount();` return the number of rows returned, and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE liked_post_id = :id;` will return only 1 row, a row with the number of likes.

You must read the contents of that row or do a complete `SELECT` this way `SELECT * FROM likes WHERE liked_post_id = :id;`. The later is less optimized, but if you are going to make a complete select in some part of your code you can reuse the returned content, so you make less queries to the database.